# Windows could not start Elastic search service locally

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-services, elasticsearch-7

I was getting this windows service error due to a recent Java update on my local machine.
[image: Elastic Search service error on start]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve it by following the steps below:

- Go to 'System Environment Variables'
- Verify 'JAVA_HOME' is pointing to the correct location. If not, change it.

  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1`
- Go to the 'bin' folder for elastic-search-7.4.2 and run below commands to remove and reinstall the service.

  `C:\elasticsearch-7.4.2\bin  elasticsearch-service.bat remove`

  `C:\elasticsearch-7.4.2\bin  elasticsearch-service.bat install`